# How to put the menu above the content?

Tags: theming

I'm developing a website with drupal 7. I want to put the menu above the content. I use zen theme. How I does it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each menu has a corresponding block that is managed on the **Blocks administration page** : admin/structure/block.

Look for your menu block and on the right dropdown, choose a region where to display it. The blocks are displayed from top to bottom in the same order than on the admin page.

[image: choose a region where to display your menu]
The regions are displayed in `sites/all/themes/zen/templates/page.tpl.php` : i.e navigation region is rendered with   `<?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>`

To see where are the regions, you can use also the link *Demonstrate block regions*, you 'll have something like :

[image: Demonstrate block regions]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have two menus wich names are "Menu principal" and "Menu socialmedia". These two menus are in the first sidebar lateral region, on the left. I modified the situation of these two menus, I put the menus in the content region, but it doesn't work. I modified the page.tpl.php,I cut and copy the sidebar code, before and after the content code... but it doesn't work... What happens? Is it possible because of content is a slideshow? The website is www.pepitablanca.com. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whenever you modify templates, don't forget to clear all caches :)

Comment: and before modifying page.tpl.php, just try the first solution. Move your main menu block from left sidebar to content, and put it above content

Comment: and this has got nothing to see with your slideshow. This is your code and the menus are still in 1rst left sidebar :`<section class="region region-sidebar-first column sidebar">
<div id="block-system-main-menu" class="block block-system block-menu first odd" role="navigation">
<div id="block-menu-menu-menu-socialmedia" class="block block-menu last even" role="navigation">`

Comment: Hey kojo, thanks for your support! I think too that the problem is in CSS. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @Kojo. Sorry, I'm a new user in stack overflow and stack exchange and i don't know about the terms and conditions to accept the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#block-system-main-menu {
   float: left;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#block-system-main-menu ul.menu
{
float: left; width: 100%;
}
#block-system-main-menu ul.menu li
{
float: left; width: 15%;
}
```

Use this css.it will help you

Simply put Your menu block above main page content block in same region and that menu will show above the rendered content or other option can be to change the order of the regions in the page.tpl.php file in your theme.

Comment: Where should I put the css?